# c++ call fmt Libary from C Code with va_args

Tags: c++, c, fmt

I'd like to use the fmt libary as part of a debugging framework.
However our project is mixed c and c++.

fmt works nice with c++ however in c we have printf() like format strings.

```
//c readable header
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

  void Foo(char* format, ...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

```
//impl.cpp
void Foo(char* format, ...)
{
  va_list aptr;

   va_start(aptr, format);

   //pass aptr to fmt lib somehow

   va_end(aptr);

}
```

Therefore I have to "hide" the C++ part from C code.
The only way (I know) in c how to do formatting is using va_args. However they will not work with fmt templates since the first one is executed at run time and the other one at compile time

=>So the Question
*Do you have an idea how to use the fmt lib from C Code?*

Thx for your Input :)

Answer (score 2):

You can call formatting functions from C via a wrapper that uses [dynamic_format_arg_store](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv2N3fmt24dynamic_format_arg_storeE) to construct argument lists at runtime. However, for that to work you'll need to know all argument types so it won't work with varargs which don't preserve the type information.

Comment: Hey thx for your answer.
But could you help me out. My C compatible call looks like
```UseFmtLib("Some {} text {}, "dummy", 2);```

the implementation looks like this

```void UseFmtLib(const char* format, ...)
{
va_list aptr;

   va_start(aptr, format);

   //can I pass aptr to vformat?
  //or can i use fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store<fmt::format_context> store(aptr);
  std::string result = fmt::vformat(format, aptr);

   va_end(aptr);
}```

Comment: You can't use aptr because va_list doesn't contain any type information.

Comment: uh damn. I was afraid you might say that :O
Thx for your help :)